# According to Routh's stability criteria when will be pole on imaginary axis?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory

I know this is easy for you. But I want to know. According to Routh's stability criteria when will be pole on imaginary axis?

Comment: The answer below seems correct. As someone who's done control in both research and industry, I am having trouble understanding when this would be relevant. RH is at most a way to derive pole locations in terms of symbolic coefficients for a plant whose characteristics are not known numerically. Historically it was different--no convenient root-finders. But now RH is comparatively depreciated.

Comment: @ALB From a practical point of view, one can say that many techniques they teach in the first course of linear control, such as RH, root locus, Nyquist,... are pretty much deprecated today. I have been working as an engineer for almost 8 years and I have never dealt with them in real world.

Comment: @polfosol I disagree. Nyquist is used all the time as is root locus. Bode plots are the de facto way of characterizing filters, SISO plants, and MIMO states which can be written as a sequential loop. A major application in aero (my field) is to use sequential loops to design autopilots. Here Nyquist is a very common tool, as is RL. RH is different because it was specifically created to ascertain linear stability when factoring a polynomial of order > 2 would be difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may already know, when we have a polynomial
$$p(s)=a_ns^n+a_{n-1}s^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$
in Routh's test, the coefficients are arranged in a table in such a way that the first row contains $a_n,a_{n-2},a_{n-4},...$ and the second row contains $a_{n-1},a_{n-3},...$ The other rows are calculated iteratively using [Routh-Hurwitz algorithm](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Routh-Hurwitz_Criterion#The_Routh_Array).

When the table is completed, the number of sign changes in the first column will be the number of non-negative poles. But sometimes the coefficients of the Routh table in **a whole row** become zero and thus further calculation of the elements of the array is not possible (i.e. table cannot be completed). This happens when there exist conjugate poles on the imaginary axis. In this case, we must use the *auxiliary polynomial*, which is built from the coefficients of the last non-zero row, and then differentiate it.

The details can be found, for example, [in here](http://www.engr.iupui.edu/~skoskie/ECE680/Routh.pdf).